# Is "Ultra320 LVD SCSI" the correct name of the interface?

Tags: scsi, hostadapter

I have a HP Ultrium 960 tape drive, but I can't figure out what the SCSI interface is called.

The [white paper](http://ftp.compaq.com/pub/products/storageworks/whitepapers/5983-0148EN.pdf) doesn't mention it

According to [this](http://www.sunstarco.com/Tape%20Drives/Hewlett%20Packard/HP%20Ultrium%20960.htm) site it is called "Ultra320 LVD SCSI".

I can't find any PCI-E controllers with a "Ultra320 LVD SCSI" interface.

Does it go under a different name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably cause its a *really* old interface that came out a while ago  - [Ultra320 is the interface itself, while LVD refers to the signalling method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCSI#Parallel_SCSI), and SCSI is a pain in the rear when it comes to varients.

The specific controller you are looking for SHOULD be called a [Ultra320 host bus adaptor](http://www.google.com/search?q=ultra320%20host%20bus%20adaptor), though you need to be careful to get a PCI-E rather than a PCI-X adaptor (of course, if you're messing with tape drives, you would know this)

Edit: apologies for the google link, but that was the most time-insensitive way to link the specific class of device i could think of. I'll update it to something less.. googly when i can find a better link

Comment: I am seriously glad that you mentioned PCI-E vs. PCI-X. I was about to get a PCI-X card. Thanks for pointing that out.